# Date Changes After Formatting It to "YYYY-MM-DD" In C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-conversion

My date changes values when I format it to "yyyy-mm-dd". It becomes "2019-54-10" instead of keeping the correct DateTime.Now. Bellow is my code:

```
public static DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
ConvertedCurrentDate = CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: use capital MM for the Month. Lower case mm is minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*mm* stands for Minute
you have to use *MM*

```
CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
ConvertedCurrentDate = CurrentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You need MM for the month :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Date strings */
public static string TodayNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");        // e.g 07
public static string ThisMonthNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");    // e.g 03
public static string ThisMonthShort = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");  // e.g Mar
public static string ThisMonthLong = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");  // e.g March
public static string ThisYearNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");   // e.g 2014
```